# How can I pass a renderRow object as a Navigator prop?

Tags: react-native

I am following the eponymous 'BookBrowser' example - a common app to teach React Native to n00bs but which unfortunately often uses NavigatorIOS rather than Navigator to explain navigation to students.

I decided to give it a take and managed to pass static props through the 'route' Navigator object. However I am stuck in actually passing a renderRow object (from ListView). Example:

```
renderResults() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderBooks}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
    );
  }

  renderBooks(book) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.button}
        underlayColor={'#F25F5D'}
        onPress={this.onBookPress}
        >
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>
            {book.name}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
```

I tried to use this function to no avail to pass book name prop.

```
  onBookPress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({name: 'bookdetails', dummy: this.props.name});
  }
```

I get undefined when I consume it from the child. I tried other combinations including this.props.book.name, etc.

Can you point me to a working code or guide me where I am mistaken?

PS: As I stated, I managed to pass a static prop successfully to the child component, so the issue is how to pass the rendered row..

Comment: Umm I think you're missing book object in renderRow. You are calling row renderer, but you are not giving book to renderBooks. I would try it like this:  `renderRow={(book) => this.renderBooks(book)}` as far as I know, everything else looks fine

Comment: Thanks @Vikky but this did not solve the problem. Please check my own answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out after some time. For the sake of future readers of this post, all I needed to do is pass the book object as an argument to the onPress callback function. This object can be made available as a prop to navigator - I chose 'route' as it is already available to the navigator.